# What flagging is for?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, comment-flags

What is the purpose of flagging a post or comment? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell moderators, that a post is:

- Offensive, Abusive, Hate Speech
- Spam
- or requires Moderator attention

And for several close reasons, if you have enough rep to use these.